# Give type to a member of parent class on the basis of constructor parameter and its initial value

Tags: typescript, types

I have a parent class say Animal like that.

```
class Animal {
  constructor(customProperties){
    this.properties = { legs: 4, wings: false, ...customProperties }
  }
  public properties // How to give type here as same as the value defined in the constructor and customProperties came in the customProperties.
}
```

where my child class is

```
class Kangaroo extends Animals {
  super({legs: 2, mamal: true});
}
```

Now how can I give the type of `properties` in the parent class as same as it's value **UNION** the `customProperties` came into the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's add types to the `Mammal` class.

```
interface AnimalProperties {
  legs: number;
  wings: boolean;
}

class Animal<T> {
  constructor(customProperties: T) {
    this.properties = { legs: 4, wings: false, ...customProperties };
  }

  public properties: AnimalProperties & T;
}
```

By using a generic class, we can allow the animal to have properties we don't know in advance. Example:

```
const { legs, wings, predator } = new Animal({ predator: false }).properties;
```

Now we can move to the specialized `Kangaroo` class. It represents a mixture of `Animal` and some additional properties. Let's call them `KangarooProperties`.

Note: overriding `AnimalProperties` should be possible, but not mandatory. That's why I extend `Partial<AnimalProperties>`.

```
interface KangarooProperties extends Partial<AnimalProperties> {
  mammal: true;
}

class Kangaroo<T> extends Animal<KangarooProperties & T> {
  constructor(customProperties: T) {
    super({ legs: 2, mammal: true, ...customProperties })
  }
}
```

Our final `properties` are correctly recognized.

```
const { cute, legs, mammal, wings } = new Kangaroo({ cute: true }).properties;
```

If your `Kangaroo` is not supposed to take any options itself, you can skip the generic part.

```
interface KangarooProperties extends Partial<AnimalProperties> {
  mammal: true;
}

class Kangaroo extends Animal<KangarooProperties> {
  constructor() {
    super({ legs: 2, mammal: true })
  }
}
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20AnimalProperties%20%7B%0A%20%20legs%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20wings%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Animal%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(customProperties%3A%20T)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.properties%20%3D%20%7B%20legs%3A%204%2C%20wings%3A%20false%2C%20...customProperties%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20public%20properties%3A%20AnimalProperties%20%26%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20KangarooProperties%20extends%20Partial%3CAnimalProperties%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20mammal%3A%20true%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Kangaroo%20extends%20Animal%3CKangarooProperties%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super(%7B%20legs%3A%202%2C%20mammal%3A%20true%20%7D)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks a lot @Karol

Comment: Hi, is this possible to make the constructor parameter of Animal class optional?

Comment: I guess you could do `constructor(customProperties: T = {} as T)`.